# Trouble Understanding Proof About Polynomials

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

In the question I have to prove that:

> There is no polynomial $P (x) = a_n x^n + a_{n−1}x^{n−1} + · · · + a_0$ with integer coefficients and of degree at least 1 with the property that $P(0), P(1), P(2), \ldots$ are all prime numbers.

The solution given is as follows:

> Assume the contrary and let $P(0) = p$, $p$ prime. Then $a_0 = p$ and $P(kp)$ is divisible by $p$ for all $k \geq 1$. Because we assumed that all these numbers are prime, it follows that $P(kp) = p$ for $k \geq 1$. Therefore, $P(x)$ takes the same value infinitely many times, a contradiction. Hence the conclusion.

For the most part I understand the proof, up until the point where it is stated that $P(x)$ takes the same value infinitely... Doesn't this mean we have an infinite number of primes and so the theorem is incorrect? Please help me understand the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

The part that you said you understood includes the fact that $P(kp)=p$ for all integers $k\geq 1$.  So $P$ takes the same value, namely $p$, at infinitely many arguments, namely $p$, $2p$, $3p$, etc.

Comment: meaning there is an infinite number of primes, but I'm meant to prove this is not true...

Comment: @fYre Your comment doesn't make sense to me.  My answer was about one single prime, namely $p$. This one prime is the "same value" mentioned in my answer and in the second  block of quoted material in your question. I don't see how you got to "an infinite number of primes" from any of this.

Comment: I meant if P(0) = p, P(1p) = p, P(2p) = p, P(3p) = p, means we have a polynomial which can generate a prime number an infinite number of times